# Angular UI-Calendar can't get eventSources to go

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using angular ui-calendar and I am trying to pass `$scope.eventSources` an object coming from my back end. I have confirmed that the object exists. It looks like this:

```
, "eventSources" : [
                   {
                     "title": 'All Day Test Event',
                     "start": new Date(2017, 0, 10)
                   },
                   {
                     "title": 'Long Test Event',
                     "start": new Date(2017, 0, 10),
                     "end": new Date(2017, 0, 19)
                   },
                   {
                     "title": 'Test Appointment',
                     "start": new Date(2017, 0, 10),
                     "end": new Date(2017, 0, 17),
                     "allDay": false
                   }
                 ]
```

If I hardcode the events in, I can confirm that the calendar shows the events, like such:

```
 $scope.eventSources =
           [
             [
              {
             title: 'All Day Test Event',
             start: new Date(2017, 0, 9)
           },
           {
             title: 'Long Test Event',
             start: new Date(2017, 0, 10),
             end: new Date(2017, 0, 12)
           },
           {
             title: 'Test Appointment',
             start: new Date(2017, 0, 8),
             end: new Date(2017, 0, 21),
             allDay: false
           }
            ]
          ];
```

When I try to pass the object to `$scope.eventSources` like this:

```
$scope.eventSources = [vm.myPractice[0].eventSources]
```

it doesn't show anything on the calendar.  Could someone please weigh in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution I found. It's a bit hacky, but it worked

```
        function loadPatient() {
            $scope.eventSources = vm.myPractice[0].eventSources;
            uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCal.fullCalendar('removeEvents');
            uiCalendarConfig.calendars.myCal.fullCalendar('addEventSource', vm.myPractice[0].eventSources);
        }
```